# Calculate the measure of a measurable set under nonlinear mapping.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

It is known that:

If $\cal{A} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue measurable, and $L: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear mapping, then $L(\cal{A})$ is Lebesgue measurable and
\begin{align}
\mu(L({\cal{A}})) = |\det L|\mu(\cal{A}),
\end{align}
where $\mu({\cal A})$ is the Lebesgue measure of ${\cal A}$, and $|x|$ returns the absolute value of a real number $x$.

But what if the mapping is nonlinear? In particular, if $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuously differentiable nonlinear mapping (but is not bijective), what the value $\mu(F({\cal{A}}))$ should be? Are there any textbooks for explaining it? Thank you very much!

Comment: The question is quite broad, and I doubt there will be a general formula to simply calculate $\mu(F(\mathcal A))$ because the set of mappings you allow is huge and varied.

Comment: There is the following generalization of the usual change of variables formula: If $f : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz, then $\int_A |\det(Df)| \, dx = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} |A \cap f^{-1}(\{y\})| \, dy$, where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of a set. The right-hand side coincides with $\mu(f(A))$ **if $f$ is injective** (otherwise you have to take "multiplicities" into account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where $F$ is injective, you have $\mu(F(A)) = \int_A |\det DF| \; d\mu$ where $DF$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F$.  If it's not injective, find (if possible) a measurable set $B$ such that $F$ is one-to-one on $B$ and $F(B) = F(A)$, and then $\mu(F(A)) = \mu(F(B)) = \int_B |\det DF|\; d\mu$.